# C++ vtknetCDFCFReader reading variables with different dimensions issues

Tags: c++, vtk, netcdf

I was trying to read my nc file. There are 3 variables in it, they are:

zonalWind         (height, lon, lat)

meridionalWind    (height, lon, lat)

verticalVelocity  (height_2, lon, lat)

Below is my code reading the arrays:

```
vtkNetCDFCFReader *reader = vtkNetCDFCFReader::New();
reader->SetFileName(fileName);
reader->SetOutputTypeToStructured();
reader->UpdateMetaData();
reader->Update();
reader->Print(std::cout);

reader->SetVariableArrayStatus("verticalVelocity", 1);
reader->SetVariableArrayStatus("zonalWind", 1);
reader->SetVariableArrayStatus("meridionalWind", 1);
```

But then I got the following error in termianl skipping the verticalVelocity array because of the dimension problem:

```
vtkNetCDFCFReader (0x7fb1f1517350): Variable verticalVelocity dimensions (height_2 lat lon) are different than the other variable dimensions (height lat lon).  Skipping
```

Is there any method I can read in all 3 variable data instead of "skipping", and do some processing afterwards?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

No. You should create 2 vtkNetCDFCFReader instances and read variables with the same dimensions for each.

If you want to extract just a portion of the larger grid and use those values on the smaller grid, then attach a vtkExtractGrid filter to one or both of the reader outputs to obtain datasets of the same size. Finally, run a vtkMergeArrays filter on the results to generate a single dataset with all the array values.

Comment: I created the second reader for the "verticalVelocity" variable, but still, it was skipping the data due to the same problem. It seems like the program defaulted the dimension to (height lat lon). Am I suppose to use SetDimension to change it? @Drone2537

Comment: Update: Just realize I have to place the SetDimension function before the reader update function. It works now.

Comment: Hi, do you happen to know also how to solve this issue? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298315/vtk-how-to-use-vtknetcdfcfreader-to-read-an-array-or-variable-array-at-specifi